# Request.IsAuthenticated always true. Wham am I missing?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I'm trying to add username to cookie and clear it on logouts but `Request.IsAuthenticated` returns always true so I'm not able to know if it is a member or not on the next page.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
 public void Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon(); // trying everything...
    }



protected void signin_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //checklogins...
        HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username_top.Text, true);
    }
```

I'm clicking the Logout from javascript function, and it hits the debugger so I'm sure that its being called.

I'm checking the value on `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isAuth = Request.IsAuthenticated; // always true !!!
        if (isAuth)
        {
            registeredDiv.Visible = true;
            guestDiv.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

What am I missing? How can I know if the user is logged in or not?

Edit: I found out that `authenticationMode` was set to Windows in web.config.

Edited it as:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```

But now it always returns false. I tried redirecting after login to same page yet still didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say that you are hitting the debugger and making the call through Javascript, are you doing this via ajax? I'm wondering that you are indeed signing out, but not redirecting the user, which means that the cookie the user has on there machine is not being overwritten/destroyed so that when they next request a page, it works again because the cookie still exists.

When the user hits your logout button on your site, you really need to have them redirect to a new page so that the cookies can be set (or unset as it were) properly...Here's the [MSDN Article on Forms Authentication Signout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx) and its example code calls `RedirectToLoginPage()` which will sort out the cookies as previously mentioned.

I've found [FireCookie for Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firecookie/) really helpful in debugging cookie related issues.

**Edit**
According to the MSDN article I linked to:

> You can use the SignOut method in
>   conjunction with the
>   RedirectToLoginPage method to log one
>   user out and allow a different user to
>   log in.

Your code does not have `RedirectToLoginPage` called, so just calling `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` isn't enough (unless you are going to manually do the work of RedirectToLoginPage)

**Edit 2**
Perhaps change your Sign In Button code to use this function instead:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username_top.Text, true)
```

As this will automatically take care of setting all the cookie stuff...

**Edit 3**
Glad you sorted it out, The above function (edit 2) would have just done what you said you had missed out on (adding the cookie to the response)...

Comment: I also have: Response.Redirect("http://localhost:36011/cartoon/default.aspx"); which redirect to the same page where I clear the cookie. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: I forgot to add the cookie to the response :) $hit happens :)

Comment: I've used Fiddler when debugged cookie related issues

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Fiddler or pretty much any of the built in browser dev tools these days will be enough