# Request.IsAuthenticated is always True

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Every HttpRequest to any page in the Asp.net App is somehow authenticated. I check it by printing the debug information in the view:

```
<p>Request.IsAuthenticated: <%= Request.IsAuthenticated %></p>
```

Authentification mode for the project is set to "Windows" in `Web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Even simple HTTP request without cookies turns out to be authenticated.

What is the cause of this behavior? Did I miss some setting in `Web.config`?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Request.IsAuthenticated always true. Wham am I missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964347/request-isauthenticated-always-true-wham-am-i-missing)

Comment: That is now Windows authentication works, requests from the same domain are automatically authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser uses Windows Integrated Authentication - which means it automatically logs the user in using their windows credentials - without asking.

If you set `<authentication mode="Windows" />` it is going to log the user in with their Windows credentials automatically.

For more information, see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323176).

Comment: Thank you. I don't know the browser logs the user in automatically with their Windows credentials.